# DNSSEC setup for polish registrar?

Tags: dns, polish, dnssec

Nazwa, a popular polish registrar requires these values to enable DNSSEC but I have searched all over the internet and I still do not know what values to put into the Nazwa panel. Also if someone manages to know what values are needed to be inputted, please let me know where you have got the value from in the DNSSEC key.

**Polish:**

```
Identyfikator klucza:
Algorytm tworzenia klucza:
Algorytm tworzenia skrótu:
Skrót z klucza:
```

**English (Google Translate):**

```
Key ID:
Key generation algorithm:
Hash algorithm:
Abbreviation of key:
```

**Random generated DNSSEC key for use as an example:**

```
Zone is not presigned
Zone has hashed NSEC3 semantics, configuration: 1 1 1 ab
keys: 
ID = 951 (KSK), tag = 3982, algo = 8, bits = 2048   Active: 1
KSK DNSKEY = google.com IN DNSKEY 257 3 8 AwEAAaj2+VO9N2Z5lmASk837JIJTMlfBOG8w5hY9w7nYkB2BM+BnuRRNQOnZ1w67RvURfserFMq4DmotGO+vfVqeF/MCbwnlnz40xm4jEToXZ9KxuWZ+VHHAeQgS8bdyutMMLLkKLzqkUEsXoE7pFzFjljgTpgQDA0vxlfRi7DPdu8njLQVMFoXKBdzwgyFb3puXIlo6ZVZE295UPmB0XhZEeCrIQbftHPfylkn2HjTFawBgRdAe4ZKAX8bSRqQhjaQIBbwxizSnUiKe6Gc4v/NhBeVRhK7rrkX2991FuTH9+NCnwXQBC7VGZkECHEtU5vaDpcer1AAccB7sxTvgRmryFu0=
DS = google.com IN DS 3982 8 1 827bcd5f51095e8af7dbfc4ca253bec365893d1c
DS = google.com IN DS 3982 8 2 929a58d55de1b3c09b46959b5a9098fc82ce077b1b73153368374ed9a672ed94
DS = google.com IN DS 3982 8 3 b5983a9c22b1b21a6de56daa3463c394341798da52759e9fdfe09c314484be94

ID = 956 (ZSK), tag = 24921, algo = 8, bits = 1024  Active: 1
ID = 961 (ZSK), tag = 35116, algo = 8, bits = 1024  Active: 0
Zone is not presigned
Zone has hashed NSEC3 semantics, configuration: 1 1 1 ab
keys: 
ID = 951 (KSK), tag = 3982, algo = 8, bits = 2048   Active: 1
KSK DNSKEY = google.com IN DNSKEY 257 3 8 AwEAAaj2+VO9N2Z5lmASk837JIJTMlfBOG8w5hY9w7nYkB2BM+BnuRRNQOnZ1w67RvURfserFMq4DmotGO+vfVqeF/MCbwnlnz40xm4jEToXZ9KxuWZ+VHHAeQgS8bdyutMMLLkKLzqkUEsXoE7pFzFjljgTpgQDA0vxlfRi7DPdu8njLQVMFoXKBdzwgyFb3puXIlo6ZVZE295UPmB0XhZEeCrIQbftHPfylkn2HjTFawBgRdAe4ZKAX8bSRqQhjaQIBbwxizSnUiKe6Gc4v/NhBeVRhK7rrkX2991FuTH9+NCnwXQBC7VGZkECHEtU5vaDpcer1AAccB7sxTvgRmryFu0=
DS = google.com IN DS 3982 8 1 827bcd5f51095e8af7dbfc4ca253bec365893d1c
DS = google.com IN DS 3982 8 2 929a58d55de1b3c09b46959b5a9098fc82ce077b1b73153368374ed9a672ed94
DS = google.com IN DS 3982 8 3 b5983a9c22b1b21a6de56daa3463c394341798da52759e9fdfe09c314484be94

ID = 956 (ZSK), tag = 24921, algo = 8, bits = 1024  Active: 1
ID = 961 (ZSK), tag = 35116, algo = 8, bits = 1024  Active: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What they need is the information to build a DS record for you. A DS record is, basically, a cryptographic hash of a DNSKEY record, which is then signed by the delegating domain. The four pieces of information they're request is (and I'm doing an educated guess here) usually called, in the order given above, "key tag", "algorithm", "digest type" and "digest". The key tag and algorithm are taken directly from the DNSKEY record, the digest type says which hashing algorithm is used and the digest is the actual hash of the DNSKEY record. The four pieces of information after "IN DS" on the DS lines in your question look like they might work if you plug them into the form.